# How much sexual content is there in DMC?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

Is there just some sexual content in the opening of DmC, or is it prevalent throughout the whole game or at least some other parts?

I don't want to a start a discussion about whether or not sex in video games is good or bad, I just wanna know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the ESRB rates a game, they include information about the games content and why it received the rating it did. In the case of *DmC Devil May Cry*, they say the following on its sexual content:

> Some scenes also depict sexual activity: scantily clad strippers dancing/gyrating provocatively with each other; a woman moving her head toward Dante's lap (fellatio is implied). During one cutscene, moaning sounds can be heard while a female character is bent over a table—a man is positioned behind her, though there is no actual depiction of the sex act. A handful of still images (i.e., concept art) portray women with exposed breasts and/or buttocks.

You can find the full break down of the rating on the [ESRB website](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=32522&Title=DmC%20Devil%20May%20Cry).

Comment: My question is not "IF" there is sexual content, but where in the game. On some sources I read that there is just this explicit strong sexual opening and besides that no sexual content anymore. I just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: @souichiro Most of this is at the beginning, but not all of it. There seem to be a few *scandalous* moments later in the game as well. If you want (and don't mind being spoiled) you can check out [all the cutscenes in advanced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trK_b0cM_uU)